# How to write the right syntax Header of CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER for send message to telegram bot

Tags: php, codeigniter, telegram-bot

I want to send notification message via Telegram bot.
So. Here is my code:

```
//php controller.
        $curl = curl_init();
        $header = [
            'key: this-key',
            'value: 1234',
            'description: '
        ];
        $params = [
            'username' => '998877',
            'massage' => 'This is my message!',
        ];

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.com/index.php?d=bot&c=Data&m=send_message',
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);
        echo $response;
```

This code return `error: invalid API Key`
But when I try to send message with postman with the same header and params, the message was sended.

My question is how to write the right syntax so THAT my telegram message can be send.

Comment: The  `$header` array is not formatted correctly, you need to format as PHP array `'key' => 'value'` instead of JSON `key: value`

Comment: Hi Jacob, I already trying formatted array `'key' => 'value'` but the result is `error: invalid API Key` so I formatted array like that.

Comment: Turns out I was wrong anyway, the formatting in your post is correct.

Comment: Have you considered using a library? https://github.com/telegram-bot-php/core

Comment: But why the result is error? Even though I tried in the Postman the result was success

Comment: In this case I cannot use any library.

Comment: Can you link to the documentation for that API endpoint you are using there?